# Kafka Connect Task Unassigned State

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a 3 node Confluent Kafka Cluster Running. I have installed the Confluent 5.0.0, Started the connect service with `nohup <Start connect-distributed> >/dev/null 2>&1` command.
I have an existing MSSQL connector task which was running earlier. When I tried starting the connector, connector was not started, and the task status was unassigned. Tried restarting the task as well as the connector, but no luck.
Do we have any option to recover the connector and the task?

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant logs from the Kafka Connect worker (which you won't get if you're redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null` )

Comment: Also Confluent Platform 5.0 is fairly old, you might want to update to 5.5

Comment: Yeah! I am not having logs. Do we have any other way to get the logs or recover back the connector.

Comment: Yes; don't run Kafka Connect like that :) Direct the logs to a file and then see what they say.